# smarty path problem

Tags: smarty

here is my folder

```
index.php
smartyhere
  -Smarty.class.php
admin
  -index.php
  -users.php
```

in index.php -> $smarty->display('index.tpl');

in admin/index.php -> $smarty->display('adminindex.tpl');
     got error Smarty error: unable to read resource: "adminindex.tpl"

any idea ?
thx

Comment: Can you please include the smarty folders and files too?

Answer (score -3):

try to understand code

which urlencode is doing path

```
<?php

print_r($file);

if (isset($file)) {
    $var = explode("-", $file);
    print_r($var);
    $prefix = $var[0];
    $script = $var[1];
} else {
    $file = "c-home1";
    $prefix = "c";
    $script = "home";
    $modid = 0;
}

if ($script=="") {
    $script="prod_list";
}

/*
* following code finds out the modules from suffix
* and find out the script name
*/
switch ($prefix) {
    case "c":
        $module = "content";
        break;
    case "m":
        $module = "myaccount";
        break;
    default:
        $module = "content";
        break;
}

$smarty->assign("module",$module);

/*
* following code finds out the modules from suffix and
* find out the script name
*/
$include_script .= $module."/".$script.".php";

if (file_exists($include_script)) {
    include_once $include_script;
} else {
    include_once "content/error.php";
}

if ($script!='home') {
    if ($script == 'termsandcondition') {
        $smarty->display("content/termsandcondition.tpl");
    } else {
        $smarty->display("template.tpl");
    }
} else {
    $smarty->display("template_home.tpl");
    $smarty->assign("msg", $msg);
    $smarty->assign("msglogin", $msglogin);
}
```